# Receiving a MYSQL error but I can't understand what's happening

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a .sql file that I'm using to populate the tables in a database. The following is the code that I am using.

```
CREATE TABLE Worker (
   worker_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   fname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   lname varchar(20) NOT NULL,


   primary key(worker_id)
   );


CREATE TABLE Customer (
  customer_id int NOT NULL Auto_Increment,
  primary key (customer_id)
   );

CREATE TABLE Orders (
 Orders_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 customer_id int NOT NULL,
 worker_id int NOT NULL,
 Orders_detail_id int NOT NULL,
 Orders_Placed date NOT NULL,
 Delivered_on date NOT NULL,
 Total varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 Ship_addr varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 Order_status varchar(35) NOT NULL,

 primary key(Orders_id),
 foreign key(customer_id) references Customer(customer_id),
 foreign key(worker_id) references Worker(worker_id),
 foreign key(Orders_detail_id) references orders_detail(Orders_detail_id)
 );

CREATE TABLE orders_detail (
   Orders_detail_id int NOT NULL Auto_Increment,
   Product_id int NOT NULL,
   Quantity varchar(4) NOT NULL,

   primary key (Orders_detail_id, Product_id)
   );

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
  Product_id int NOT NULL Auto_Increment,
  Prod_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  Prod_desc varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Prod_price varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  Quantity_left varchar(4) NOT NULL,

  primary key (Product_id)
  );
```

- When trying to run the file, I receive the following error:

`ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 27: Can't create table 'houston.ORDERS' (errno: 150)`

I would appreciate if I could get a hint as to why I receive the error.

Comment: I think your `orders` table references `orders_details` which is created after `orders` has created. Try creating the `order_details` table first before `orders`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to add foreign key constraint from Orders to  orders_detail. Try moving create table of orders_detail before order

Comment: it worked, guess that makes sense, should've known I can't reference something that isn't there.  I marked the answer as helpful

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `orders` table before the `orders_detail` table - `foreign key(Orders_detail_id)` references `orders_detail(Orders_detail_id)` searches for the table `orders_detail` which is created after this query.

Use this code, just tested it and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE Worker (
   worker_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   fname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   lname varchar(20) NOT NULL,

   primary key(worker_id)
);


CREATE TABLE Customer (
   customer_id int NOT NULL Auto_Increment,
   primary key (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders_detail (
   Orders_detail_id int NOT NULL Auto_Increment,
   Product_id int NOT NULL,
   Quantity varchar(4) NOT NULL,

   primary key (Orders_detail_id, Product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
   Orders_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   customer_id int NOT NULL,
   worker_id int NOT NULL,
   Orders_detail_id int NOT NULL,
   Orders_Placed date NOT NULL,
   Delivered_on date NOT NULL,
   Total varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   Ship_addr varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   Order_status varchar(35) NOT NULL,

   primary key(Orders_id),
   foreign key(customer_id) references Customer(customer_id),
   foreign key(worker_id) references Worker(worker_id),
   foreign key(Orders_detail_id) references orders_detail(Orders_detail_id)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
   Product_id int NOT NULL Auto_Increment,
   Prod_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   Prod_desc varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   Prod_price varchar(6) NOT NULL,
   Quantity_left varchar(4) NOT NULL,

   primary key (Product_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you must run this sql.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

And , you run your sqls.

After that, you run this sql.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

`foreign key(Orders_detail_id) references orders_detail(Orders_detail_id)` searches for the table `orders_detail` which is created after this query.

Insert the `CREATE TABLE Orders` query at the bottom of your script and everything should work as expected :)